# PHP Warning: Missing ALL arguments for All Function in ajaxfunctions.php

Tags: php, arguments

I have a XAJAX file by name ajaxfunctions.php with some function such:

```
function show_gallery($id){
    $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
    if(!$_SESSION["g".removeScript($id)]){
        $_SESSION["g".removeScript($id)]=1;
        updateCounterGallery($id);
    }
        $objResponse->addScriptCall("popupImages", "./cportal /form/user_gallery_ajax.php?id=".$id."");
    return $objResponse;
    }
```

When I call xajax_show_gallery(24), in original Function, the argument missed. this problem happen in each calling function that is in this file

Comment: two double quotes at end of string

Comment: @Nouphal.M: please explain more. in each function call arguments miss it's value in the function's body !!!

Comment: `?id=".$id.""` here you could try this instead `"./cportal /form/user_gallery_ajax.php?id=$id"`

Comment: Whene I try to get $id's value by:    
`function show_gallery($id){ die($id);
    $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
    if(!$_SESSION["g".removeScript($id)]){
        $_SESSION["g".removeScript($id)]=1;
        updateCounterGallery($id);
    }
        $objResponse->addScriptCall("popupImages", "./cportal /form/user_gallery_ajax.php?id=".$id."");
    return $objResponse;
    }`  `die($id);` statement Return NULL